# Applying Bayes Rule

Tags: probability, solution-verification

I'm currently revising for my exams and something in one of the slides is throwing me off.

I don't understand how Bayes Rule was applied on the following: (I understand the first line - thats simple).

> [image: Sorry, uploaded the image directly.]

I've tried using product rule to get it into a nicer form, then using chain rule, but can't seem to be getting that exact form (I'm close, I hate an extra P(e_t+1)

I would appreciate if anybody could guide me through how that simplification (if you could call it that) was obtained.

Thanks

---

Edit: I think I may have got the solution, not sure (sorry for the awful formatting, I suck at using this...):

$\mathsf P(X_{t+1} \mid e_{t+1}, e_{1:t}) = \dfrac{\mathsf P(X_{t+1}, e_{t+1}, e_{1:t})}{\mathsf P(e_{t+1}, e_{1:t})}$ by the product rule.

Omit the denominator and add a normalization constant "α" infront:

$\begin{align}
 \qquad &= \alpha \mathsf P(X_{t+1}, e_{t+1}, e_{1:t})
\\[1ex] & = \alpha \mathsf P(e_{t+1}, X_{t+1}, e_{1:t}) & \text{(just rearranging)}
\\[1ex] & = \alpha \mathsf P(e_{t+1} \mid X_{t+1}, e_{1:t})\cdot\mathsf P(X_{t+1}, e_{1:t}) & \text{(product rule)}
\end{align}$

Does this reasoning seem correct or did I just fluke my way into the answer?

Comment: Yes, it looks like you've got it.  I've edited some MathJax formatting.  Mostly the `\frac{ }{ }` for fraction, `{  }` grouping around the subscripts, and `\mathsf P` to change its font, `\text{ }` for included text, and the `\begin{align} & \\[1ex] \end{align}` alignment formatting bits on the last bit.

Comment: Thanks alot, I'll keep the formatting in mind for next time. So would you agree that my method seems correct, or did I brute force my way into the answer, so to speak?

Comment: Yes, those are the steps the missing from their explanation.

Comment: Okay, thanks alot for clarifying that for me - highly appreciated. I feel probability theory is one of those things where its possible to get the correct answer from the wrong methods. Although I'm confused why it was stated as using "Bayes Rule" when my solution did not include that at all.

Comment: Bayes' Rule is $P(A\mid B) = \frac{P(B\mid A)P(A)}{P(B)}$.  The product rule you used is $P(A, B) = P(A\mid B) P(B)  = P(B\mid A)P(A)$. So...

Comment: I used the first form, P(A,B) = P(A|B)P(B) - how does this relate to Bayes Rule? I can see that the latter equation does (even though they're both essentially the same thing).

Comment: What happens when you divide by $P(B)$ ?

Comment: $\mathsf P(A,B)/P(B) = P(A|B)$

Comment: (Sigh) @Tazman , then substitute $P(A,B)=P(B\mid A)P(A)$ to get $$P(B\mid A)P(A)\big/P(B) = P(A\mid B)$$

Comment: Oh damn. Sorry I was being really naive - I thought I already had the solution above but just now realised my I had a union where they had a condition, hence I was confused at why I needed to do further calculation.

Makes perfect sense now why you said that, thanks!